# Android Devices wrapping text to screen width

Tags: android, html, newsletter

Is there a way to stop android mobile devices wrapping text to the screen width?

Layout container widths are preserved (tables, td's) but android insists on wrapping the text to fit the screen width.

This is for html newsletters so I need something to stick in a media query and nothing in

```
<head></head>
```

tag as this will get stripped by the mail client.

Cheers

Comment: are you talking about changing the layout_width of your text field in the xml?

Comment: No xml. I have a .html file with all css inline (it needs to be for html newsletters/ezines). The problem is the android device wraps text in the viewport to the device width but preserves the layout size of the container element. I'm looking for perhaps a media query with a viewport meta value i can use to stop this text wrapping.

Comment: I also have this question! Did you managed it?

Comment: Hi Leonel. Haven't looked into it since i got no hits here! I would have thought this was a common issue. Hopefully someone will see these updates and it might get an answer!

Comment: Can you provide a simple sample so we can test it? use http://www.jsfiddle.net or provide a link

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back! 

http://jsfiddle.net/YrPJt/2/

So here the text would be wrapped on android to the view port width which will be circa 480px. So I'm wondering is there a way to stop text wrapping as the container isn't resized.

Comment: You'd need to stick this html up on a webpage to get the idea though as it won't display as intended the jfiddle presents it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**!

You can easily achieve that using the CSS code "*white-space: nowrap*".

You could just prevent wrapping on certain part of the newsletter/page with the inline CSS:

```
style="white-space: nowrap"
```

Pretty easy uh? ;)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that! I don't have an android to check at the moment unfortunately but will this wrap to the container or do i need to put in manual line breaks? Thanks.